# Add a . in front of every new sentence in Word MACRO VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I set up a macro to add a . in front of every new empty line?

from:

Lorem ipsum

Lorem ipsum

Lorem ipsum

to:

Lorem ipsum

```
.
```

Lorem ipsum

```
.
```

Lorem ipsum

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. If you do post something there, you should delete this question or at least add a link in your question here to the new question there to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search and replace `^p^p` with `^p.^p`. Using *Alt+T*, *M*, *R* will record the search and replace and write code for you.